# Php Laravel a lot of if in seed

Tags: php, laravel

I have a very long if to make my seed. Is there a possibility to make it shorter?
Now it works, but looks not nice :(. I was thinking that it can be maybe in one loop for, but I can't write it :( 
Here is my code:

```
$seed = rand(0, 2);

        if ($seed == 2) {
            $o->statuses()->attach(OrderStatusName::STATUS_DOWNLOADED_IN_STORE,
                ['set_at' => $beginTime->add($int)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
            $randOperating = rand(0, 2);
            if ($randOperating == 1) {
                $o->statuses()->attach(OrderStatusName::STATUS_OPERATING_IN_WAREHOUSE,
                    ['set_at' => $beginTime->add($int)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
                $randCompleted = rand(0, 2);
                if ($randCompleted > 1) {
                    $o->statuses()->attach(OrderStatusName::STATUS_COMPLETED_IN_WAREHOUSE,
                        ['set_at' => $beginTime->add($int)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
                    $randTrack = rand(0, 2);
                    if ($randTrack == 2) {
                        $o->statuses()->attach(OrderStatusName::STATUS_IN_TRACK,
                            ['set_at' => $beginTime->add($int)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
                        $deliveredSeed = rand(0, 2);
                        if ($deliveredSeed == 2) {
                            $o->statuses()->attach(OrderStatusName::STATUS_DELIVERED_TO_STORE,
                                ['set_at' => $beginTime->add($int)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
                            $pastSeed = rand(0, 3);
                            if ($pastSeed < 2) {
                                $o->statuses()->attach(self::ORDER_PAST_STATUSES[$pastSeed],
                                    ['set_at' => $beginTime->add($int)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If your code works keep it like that... Making it shorter will only make it less maintainable and/or readable. Marking this question as too opinionated to get answer...

Comment: Maybe you could use early exits (returns) to unravel the ifs. The code won't be shorter, but not so indented and maybe easier to read because of that. I'm curious though what happens here. And order process that works at random? Which shop do you work for? Maybe this explains why they don't always deliver. ;-)

Comment: @GolezTrol he is seeding his table with fake data to make tests, if they really work like that would be a real hell jajaja

Comment: I don't really understand why sometimes you use `==1`, then `>1` then `==2`. In the end you're just looking for a 1 in 3 chance, right?

Comment: @GolezTrol Because he is looking to generate random statuses he could use another system but it is valid too. One of every three would have the next status the other two the status before to this. (this is the concept)

Answer (score 1):

I'm supposing that every status need the before to status to make logic. I create an array with all statuses in logic order and then generating one position ramdonly to loop them and create every needed status.

```
$pastSeed = rand(0, 3);
$cases = [OrderStatusName::STATUS_DOWNLOADED_IN_STORE,OrderStatusName::STATUS_OPERATING_IN_WAREHOUSE,OrderStatusName::STATUS_COMPLETED_IN_WAREHOUSE,OrderStatusName::STATUS_IN_TRACK,self::ORDER_PAST_STATUSES[$pastSeed],NULL];

$case = rand(0,sizeof($cases));

if($cases[$case] != null){
   for($i = 0; $i<=$case; $i++){
       $o->statuses()->attach($cases[$i],['set_at' => $beginTime->add($int)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in a loop, especially the first part, since they are fixed statuses. The last one is a different case with a different random number, but mainly because it gets value from an array based on the random number, so you would get a loop and something else...

```
$checknext = true;
$statuses = [
  OrderStatusName::STATUS_DOWNLOADED_IN_STORE,
  OrderStatusName::STATUS_OPERATING_IN_WAREHOUSE,
  OrderStatusName::STATUS_COMPLETED_IN_WAREHOUSE,
  OrderStatusName::STATUS_IN_TRACK,
  OrderStatusName::STATUS_DELIVERED_TO_STORE
];

foreach($statuses as $status) {
  if (!($checknext = rand(0, 2) == 2))
    break;
  }
  $o->statuses()->attach($status, ['set_at' => $beginTime->add($int)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
}
if ($checknext && ($pastSeed = rand(0, 3)) < 2) {
  $o->statuses()->attach(self::ORDER_PAST_STATUSES[$pastSeed],
    ['set_at' => $beginTime->add($int)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
}
```

You could even make it more advanced, and add `self::ORDER_PAST_STATUSES` to the array too. Inside the loop you can check if it's an array and in that case do the slightly different handling in the form of:

```
  if (is_array($status)) {
    $max = count($status)*2-1;
    $rand = rand(0, $max);
    if ($rand < count($status) {
      $o->statuses()->attach($status[$rand},  .... );
    }
  }
```

Other ways to make it more flexible is to add not just the status, but also the chance to the array of statuses. In the loop you could check

```
rand(0, $chance) == 1
```

or for the array:

```
count($status) * $chance - 1
```

I wanted to show the possibility, but if you ask me this adds a lot of complexity while saving very little code. Order statuses are probably not going to change a lot either, so you won't have to touch this code very often. In the end, I would go for the early-exit solution which I mentioned in the comment before, and which is demonstrated by madpoet in his answer.

Comment: just an appointment, your logic doesn't contemplate the NULL status ( no status for order ). And one question, what is the role for self::ORDER_PAST_STATUSES[$pastSeed] in his logic? BTW nice answer

Comment: @aaron0207 Thanks, It seemed to me that the statuses are sequential, you go optionally to in store, then optionally to in warehouse, then optionally to completed... until the last one, where optionally one state is selected from an array of states. I tried to add that same logic. In the question there is no null status, although even adding the first status is decided on random. I think I covered that in my answer as well; if the first rand call returns 1, the code exits without adding any status to the order.

Answer (score 0):

I think since you need to do a random number in each if, and all conditions are different, you would actually need to write a lot more code than what you have posted to define each condition and each status. One thing I would do however is to single out the repeated code so it looks slimmer.

```
$randNumber = function ( $value = 2 ) {
    return rand(0, $value);
};

$attachStatus = function ( $status ) use ( $o, $int ) {
    $o->statuses()->attach($status, ['set_at' => $beginTime->add($int)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
};

if ($randNumber() == 2) {
    $attachStatus( OrderStatusName::STATUS_DOWNLOADED_IN_STORE );
    if ($randNumber() == 1) {
        $attachStatus( OrderStatusName::STATUS_OPERATING_IN_WAREHOUSE );
        if ($randNumber() > 1) {
            $attachStatus( OrderStatusName::STATUS_COMPLETED_IN_WAREHOUSE );
            if ($randNumber() == 2) {
                $attachStatus( OrderStatusName::STATUS_IN_TRACK );
                if ($randNumber() == 2) {
                    $attachStatus( OrderStatusName::STATUS_DELIVERED_TO_STORE );
                    $pastSeed = $randNumber(3);
                    if ($pastSeed < 2) {
                        $attachStatus( self::ORDER_PAST_STATUSES[$pastSeed] );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it with loops it'll be a nightmare when you need to make changes later. A common practice to avoid nested ifs is to use 'early exits'.

I also removed some unnecessary variables and extracted a variable for the set_at property for better readability. If the code is inside a loop don't forget to replace `return` with `continue`.

You can also use private methods inside the seed class for better readability.

```
$params = ['set_at' => $beginTime->add($int)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')];

// Downloaded in store
if (rand(0, 2) != 2) return;
$o->statuses()->attach(OrderStatusName::STATUS_DOWNLOADED_IN_STORE, $params);

// Operating in warehouse
if (rand(0, 2) != 1) return;
$o->statuses()->attach(OrderStatusName::STATUS_OPERATING_IN_WAREHOUSE, $params);

// Completed in warehouse
if (rand(0, 2) != 2) return;
$o->statuses()->attach(OrderStatusName::STATUS_COMPLETED_IN_WAREHOUSE, $params);

// In track
if (rand(0, 2) != 2) return;
$o->statuses()->attach(OrderStatusName::STATUS_IN_TRACK, $params);

// Delivered to store
if (rand(0, 2) != 2) return;
$o->statuses()->attach(OrderStatusName::STATUS_DELIVERED_TO_STORE, $params);

// Past status
$pastSeed = rand(0, 3);
if ($pastSeed != 3) return;
$o->statuses()->attach(self::ORDER_PAST_STATUSES[$pastSeed], $params);
```